# How to parallelize webservice requests with CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, spring, completable-future

I have a servlet request that basically requests data given by an input date. As I have multiple dates, I have to send multiple requests, and then aggregate the results. For example:

```
List<Result> results = new ArrayList<>();

for (LocalDate date : dates) {
    ServletReq req = new ServletReq(date);

    try {
        ServletRsp rsp = webservice.send(req);
        results.addAll(rsp.getResults());
    } catch (SpecificException e) {
        //just ignore this result and continue
    }
}
```

Question: how can I parallelize the code above? Means: sending multiple `ServletReq` async, and collect the result into the list. Wait for all requests to finish (maybe with a timeout), and ignore the `SpecificException`.

I started as follows, but neither do I know if this is the right direction, nor did I succeed transfering the code above completely. Especially regarding the exception to be ignored.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
List<CompletableFuture<ServletRsp>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

for (LocalDate date : dates) {
    ServletReq req = new ServletReq(date);
    CompletableFuture future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> webservice.send(req), service);
    futures.add(future);
}

CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()])).join();
```

So far, but: How can I call `rsp.getResults()` on the async result, and put everything into the `list`. And how can I ignore the `SpecificException` during the async execution? (I cannot modify the `webservice.send()` method!).

Comment: you can traverse through the futurelist and put a try catch block aroung Future.get(). FutureTask.get() will re-throw any exception thrown by the task as an ExecutorException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- catch them within the supplier and return e.g. `null`. Only do that if you'd really do nothing with the exception anyways. To get the results at `future.get()` you have to deal with `null` and `ExecutionException`s.

Eg

```
CompletableFuture<ServletRsp> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    try {
        return webservice.send(new ServletReq(date));
    } catch (SpecificException e) {
        return null;
    }
});
```

- rethrow them as (custom?) `RuntimeException` so you don't lose them. Now you deal with just exceptions in the end but some are double-wrapped.
- Manually complete the future.

E.g.

```
CompletableFuture<ServletRsp> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
service.execute(() -> {
    try {
        future.complete(webservice.send(new ServletReq(date));
    } catch (SpecificException e) {
        future.completeExceptionally(e);
    }
});
futures.add(future);
```

No more wrapping besides in `ExecutionException`. `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` does about exactly that, but has no code to deal with checked exceptions.

- Just use the good old `ExecutorService#submit(Callable<T> callable)` method which accepts code that throws:

e.g.

```
List<Callable<String>> tasks = dates.stream()
        .map(d -> (Callable<ServletRsp>) () -> send(new ServletReq(d)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Future<ServletRsp>> completed = service.invokeAll(tasks);
```

Comment: So you last approach with traditional `Callable` probably fits best. If any exception is thrown, I can catch it using `future.get();`, which I anyways have to call to get the response. `invokeAll()` blocks until all tasks are finished. Which is fine as afterwards I can just iterate the futures and aggregate the results to my need. I feel using `CompletableFuture` makes things more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on a good path there.

The issue is, that there is no mechanism to nicely collect the results, except doing it yourself:

```java
ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>(); // these are only references to tell you when the request finishes 
Queue<ServletRsp> results = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>(); // this has to be thread-safe

for (LocalDate date : dates) {
    ServletReq req = new ServletReq(date);
    CompletableFuture future = CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(() -> webservice.send(req), service)
            .thenAcceptAsync(results::add);
    futures.add(future);
}

CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()])).join();
// do stuff with results
```

I've tried to keep most of the code as you've written it. Maybe it's a bit cleaner with streams:

```
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> collect = dates
        .map(date -> CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(() -> webservice.send(new ServletReq(date)), service)
            .thenAcceptAsync(results::add))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // wait for all requests to finish
    CompletableFuture.allOf(collect.toArray(new CompletableFuture[collect.size()])).thenAcceptAsync(ignored -> {
        //you can also handle the response async.
    });
```